# Insert an empty row in an Excel document using PowerShell

Tags: excel, powershell

I am trying to programmatically insert a new row at a specified place in my Excel sheet, and despite extensive searching around the web I was unable to find a way to achieve this.

The following code successfully inserts an empty column:

```
$xlShiftToRight = -4161

#Get list of files
$File = Get-ChildItem c:\path\to\file.xlsx

#Launch Excel
$XL = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application

#Open the file and get the Data sheet
$WB = $XL.Workbooks.Open($File.Fullname)

$XL.Visible = $true
$Sheet = $WB.Worksheets.Item('Naira')

$objRange = $XL.Range("C3").EntireColumn
[void]$objRange.Insert($xlShiftToRight)
```

But the specular alternative - using `EntireRow` instead of `EntireColumn` does not.

**QUESTION**

How do I *insert* a row at after another specific row in an Excel document using PowerShell?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Changing just the range does not suffice. You also need to change the direction in which to move the existing cells (shifting to the right doesn't make much sense when you're inserting an entire row).

Change this:

```
$xlShiftToRight = -4161 

...

$objRange = $XL.Range("C3").EntireColumn 
[void] $objRange.Insert($xlShiftToRight)
```

into this:

```
$xlShiftDown = -4121

...

$objRange = $XL.Range("C3").EntireRow
[void]$objRange.Insert($xlShiftDown)
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. This does work - on top of this I had another problem that I didn't realise I had, I was trying to insert a new row inside a "Table", and apparently this operation is not allowed.