Excel COM object method inaccessible
I am trying to insert a new row into an Excel sheet. I open a file with Powershell, get an object for the sheet, and then get a range object like
$Range=$Sheet.Range("A1")
$Range.Insert()

As I am typing insert, Powershell will even do the tab completion. So, it sees the method there. But when I run that line, I get the error

OperationStopped: Unable to get the Insert property of the Range class

Does anyone know what is going on here, or another way to insert a row? I can't go to the end of text within the worksheet because my data is in a table and there is another table under that. So, it's not that straight-forward.

It can't guess from that shape whether you want to insert a row or a column.  You may need to specify the parameter.

From Related Questions, below: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57960250/insert-an-empty-row-in-an-excel-document-using-powershell?rq=2

@TimRoberts: By default (if tables don't get in the way), calling .Insert() on a single cell inserts a single cell above the targeted one (i.e. all cells in the same column are shifted downward).

In order to do so you need to call the table by name:
# Initialize Excel application
$Excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$Excel.Visible = $false  # Set to $true if you want to see Excel's window

# Open the existing workbook
$Workbook = $Excel.Workbooks.Open("C:\your\excel\path.xlsx")

# Select the worksheet containing the table
$Sheet = $Workbook.Sheets.Item(1)

# Access the table by name (or index if you prefer)
$Table = $Sheet.ListObjects.Item("YourTableName")

# Add a new row at the end of the table
$Table.ListRows.Add() | Out-Null

# Optionally, you can fill data in the newly added row (if needed)
# Let's assume you want to fill the first column of the new row
$LastRowIndex = $Table.ListRows.Count
$Table.DataBodyRange.Rows.Item($LastRowIndex).Columns.Item(1).Value2 = "New Value"

# Save and close the workbook
$Workbook.Save()
$Workbook.Close()
$Excel.Quit()

# Release the COM objects
[System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($Table)
[System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($Sheet)
[System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($Workbook)
[System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($Excel)


As an aside: while you can call [Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject() on every reference, it is simpler to execute all COM operations in a child scope (& { ... }) so that when its variables go out of scope, releasing happens automatically. You can speed up release by calling [GC]::Collect(). See this answer for details.


Preface:

This answer addresses the question as asked, namely how to insert a row into a spreadsheet as a whole.

If, by contrast, you're looking to insert rows into a table object inside a spreadsheet, see Dom's answer.



The - obscure - error message (observed in Excel version 16.0.17830.20138 / Office 2019) implies that your A1 cell is part of a table.

If it weren't, the call would succeed and insert a single cell above the current A1 cell, shifting all existing cells in column 1 downward by default (in the absence of explicitly specifying an argument indicating the direction of the insertion).[1]

Since such an operation would corrupt a table, it is prevented, although the wording of the error message is unhelpful.

In fact, a helpful error message is shown if a cell somewhere below the targeted one in the same column is part of a table (which suggests that the way the error surfaced in your case is a bug):
This won't work because it would move cells in a table on your worksheet.



To insert an entire row into the spreadsheet (as opposed to just the table), get a reference to the row above which to insert:
# Inserts a new row above the first one.
$Sheet.Rows(1).Insert()


[1] Quoting from the Range.Insert documentation, with respect to the optional Shift parameter: "Specifies which way to shift the cells. Can be one of the following XlInsertShiftDirection constants: xlShiftToRight [in PowerShell, use -4161] or xlShiftDown [in PowerShell, use -4121]. If this argument is omitted, Microsoft Excel decides based on the shape of the range." 
